# Emit every time 50 items out of a huge list

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have a List of more then 1000 items.
I want to create API call on the `OnNext` every 50 items each time.

I tried `scan` and `window` operators but it didn't work for some reason.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There is an operator called `every` in the [Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersevery) project:

```java
Flowable.range(1, 5)
.compose(FlowableTransformers.<Integer>every(2))
.test()
.assertResult(2, 4);
```

or you can use `buffer(50)` and take the last element of the buffer:

```java
Flowable.range(1, 1024)
.buffer(50)
.filter(list -> list.size() == 50)
.map(list -> list.get(49))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @andro, Keep in mind that because of the `filter list.size == 50`, if you have less than 50 items remaining, there will be no API call for those last items. For example when your list is 130 items long, it subscribe will be called twice here, not three times.